# Is Capacity Provider attached to `cluster` not `service` or `taskdefinition`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using `ECS on EC2`

What I want to do is like this below.

- task1 (admin task - light)

  - nginx container
  - django python framework  container
- task2 (AI task - heavy)

  - api container (access from django container in task1 only)
  - AI model container

So my idea is

```
cluster - service1 - taskdefinition1 - task1  (use small instance) 
        - service2 - taskdefinition2 - task2  (use big instance)
```

then At first, I made one `capacity provider` for admin task

```
const adminAutoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ASG', {
  vpc,
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.small'),
  machineImage: ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux(),  
  autoScalingGroupName:`ol-${targetEnv}-asg`,
  minCapacity:1,
  maxCapacity:3,
  vpcSubnets: {subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }
});
const adminCapacityProvider = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(this, 'AsgCapacityProvider', {
  autoScalingGroup:adminAutoScalingGroup,
  capacityProviderName: `admin-${targetEnv}-cp`
});

cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(adminCapacityProvider);// it is attached to cluster?????
```

I am confused.

`capacityprovider` should be attached to `cluster` not `service` or `taskdefinition`?

If so, is my idea (make two capacity providers and attach each to each task or service) wrong?.

Is there any best practice for this case?(including fargate)

Comment: Why not run those two tasks in separate clusters? The only advantage to running them in the same cluster is that you can have them use the same EC2 servers, but if you don't want them using the same EC2 servers then you are just making your configuration more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capacityprovider` are defined for clusters. But a cluster can have multiple capacity providers. Thus in your service you can define [capacityProviderStrategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html#sd-capacityproviderstrategy) which can choose between different providers in the cluster.

Comment: Thankyou veru much I can step forward. However I can not set `capacityProviderStrategies:[adminCapacityProvider]` in Service definition, so I should not use `AsgCapacityProvider`? (use another CapacityProvider?)