# CapacityProviderStrategies of EC2Service shows the error, The specified capacity provider ****** was not found

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

From this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245954/is-capacity-provider-attached-to-cluster-not-service-or-taskdefinition) (that is solved but this article is related)

I made two `AutoScalingGroup`, two `AsgCapacityProvider` and two `ecs on ec2` `service`

Now I want to attach these `CapacityProvider` to each `service`.

However, There is  error

`The specified capacity provider myapp-dev-admin-cp was not found`

```
const adminCapacityProvider = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(this, 'admin-asg-capacity-provider', {
  autoScalingGroup:adminAutoScalingGroup,
  capacityProviderName: `myapp-${targetEnv}-admin-cp`
});

const adminCapacityProvider2 = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(this, 'admin-asg-capacity-provider2', {
  autoScalingGroup:adminAutoScalingGroup2,
  capacityProviderName: `myapp-${targetEnv}-admin-cp2`
});

cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(adminCapacityProvider);
cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(adminCapacityProvider2);

const ecsAiService = new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'AiService', {
  cluster,
  taskDefinition:aiTaskDefinition,
  serviceName: `myapp-${targetEnv}-ai-service`,
  enableExecuteCommand:true,
  securityGroups: [adminServiceSg],
  vpcSubnets:{subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC },
  capacityProviderStrategies:[
    capacityProvider:`myapp-${targetEnv}-admin-cp`// error occurs here
  ]
})
```

I googled around and found for fargate, `FARGATE` or `FARGATE_SPOT` should be put here, however my one is `ECS on EC2`.

What should I use for capacityProviderStrategie's props?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to the fact that the service is being created before the capacity provider.

To create an implicit dependency (while also removing the need to specify the name of the capacity provider in two places), try this:

```js
...
  capacityProviderStrategies:[
    capacityProvider: adminCapacityProvider.capacityProviderName
  ]
...
```

This will let CDK know that your service depends on the capacity provider and only create it after it's been provisioned.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the orders of items created. It solves my problem!